# Pydoc not seeing docstrings?

Tags: python, pydoc

Obviously I am missing something serious here.  Here is my test program:

```
"""
Doc and nothing but doc
"""

class TestMe(object):
    """
    class documentation goes here
    """
    def testFunc(self):
        """
        FunctionDoc Goes here
        """
        print "Hello world"

if __name__ =="__main__":
    t=TestMe()
    t.testFunc()
```

I run it and it prints "Hello world", natch.
But `pydoc.py test.py` gives this:

```
no Python documentation found for 'test.py'
```

Obviously I am missing something simple here, but what?

--edit--
Per Vishnu's suggestion I added "`print t.__doc__`" to the last line of the file and now running the file gives this:

```
Hello world

    class documentation goes here
```

But pydoc still does not find any documentation.

Comment: Did you try `TestMe.__doc__`?

Comment: Have you tried the solutions posted here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040646/how-do-i-create-documentation-with-pydoc

Comment: Yup, that is what I looked at just before posting this.  And why it seems to me that my test script above is right.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Pydoc wants a module name, not a file name.  Try `pydoc test`.

It will use the argument as a file name if it has a slash in it:  `pydoc ./test.py`

Comment: Bingo!   I knew it had to be something simple.