# How to comment parameters for pydoc

Tags: python, parameters, comments, pydoc

Is there a way to comment the parameters of a function to make them recognized by the pydoc library ?

i.e what is the docstring for pydoc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to document a method with parameter(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195455/how-to-document-a-method-with-parameters)

Comment: @ Steven Vascellaro. In contrary with the possible duplicate, this question is specific to the pydoc library.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

pydoc doesn't recognise "structured" elements in docstrings, it just outputs the docstring as is. See [PEP-257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) for an example.

If you want a "formatted" documentation you should use another documentation generator, such as [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) or [pdoc](https://pdoc3.github.io/pdoc), for example.

The parameters for functions have to be documented in the functions docstring. Here is an example taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13050049/4615192):

```
"""
This example module shows various types of documentation available for use
with pydoc.  To generate HTML documentation for this module issue the
command:

    pydoc -w foo

"""

class Foo(object):
    """
    Foo encapsulates a name and an age.
    """
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        """
        Construct a new 'Foo' object.

        :param name: The name of foo
        :param age: The ageof foo
        :return: returns nothing
        """
        self.name = name
        self.age

def bar(baz):
    """
    Prints baz to the display.
    """
    print baz

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Foo('John Doe', 42)
    bar("hello world")
```

Here is another more explicit example if you want to take advantage of restructured text with more parameter descriptors, such as `:type param:` or `:rtype:` taken [from here](http://sametmax.com/les-docstrings/)

```
"""
The ``obvious`` module
======================

Use it to import very obvious functions.

:Example:

>>> from obvious import add
>>> add(1, 1)
2

This is a subtitle
-------------------

You can say so many things here ! You can say so many things here !
You can say so many things here ! You can say so many things here !
You can say so many things here ! You can say so many things here !
You can say so many things here ! You can say so many things here !

This is another subtitle
------------------------

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

"""

def add(a, b):
    """
    Adds two numbers and returns the result.

    This add two real numbers and return a real result. You will want to
    use this function in any place you would usually use the ``+`` operator
    but requires a functional equivalent.

    :param a: The first number to add
    :param b: The second number to add
    :type a: int
    :type b: int
    :return: The result of the addition
    :rtype: int

    :Example:

    >>> add(1, 1)
    2
    >>> add(2.1, 3.4)  # all int compatible types work
    5.5

    .. seealso:: sub(), div(), mul()
    .. warnings:: This is a completly useless function. Use it only in a 
              tutorial unless you want to look like a fool.
    .. note:: You may want to use a lambda function instead of this.
    .. todo:: Delete this function. Then masturbate with olive oil.
    """
    return a + b
```

You can also use different docstring formats (like [Google](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_google.html) or [Numpy](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#docstring-standard)), **which I recommend!!!** to make your docstrings clearer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I've already tried the first docstring. However, the :param is not "recognized" by pydoc and appear as the other comments in the generated html document.

Comment: Pydoc doesn't recognise "structured" elements in docstrings, it just outputs the docstring as is. See [PEP 0257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) for an example.
If you want this kind of feature, you will have to user another documentation generator as I answered above.
Sorry for the confusion, I will edit my answer

Comment: Ok, so finally the answer is "it won't work with pydoc, I could use Sphinx if I want to do that." Right ?

Comment: Yes, pydoc was designed to simply output the documentation in a terminal environment. Sphinx is fairly easy to set up.

Comment: Your todo is quite challenging...

Answer (score 4):

Another example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Module documentation
A small example of comments usage
"""

# regular comment,
# will not visible by pydoc
spam = 40


def square(x):
    """
    this function will return square(x) value
    :param x: any number
    :return: example doc for return
    """
    return x ** 2

import abc


class ListInherited:
    """
        Class ListInherited doc example
        This class use dir() function for list instance attributes
    """

    def __init__(self, arg1):
        """
        my constructor
        :param arg1: example value
        :return:
        """
        self.arg1 = arg1

    def __str__(self):
        """
        to string conversion
        :return:
        """
        tup = (self.__class__.__name__, id(self), self.attr_names())
        return '<Instance of %s, address %s:\n%s>' % tup

    def attr_names(self):
        """
        get attribute names
        :return: string
        """
        result = ''

        for attr in dir(self):
            if attr[:2] == '__' and attr[-2:] == '__':  # skip "build-in"
                result += '\t name %s=<>\n' % attr
            else:
                result += '\t name %s=%s\n' % (attr, getattr(self, attr))
        return result

    @staticmethod
    def my_static_method(count):
        """
        static method comment example
        :param count:
        :return:
        """
        return "Hello, I'm static" * count


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import test3

    x = 33
    y = test3.square(x)

    print(test3.__doc__)
    print(test3.square.__doc__)

    instance = ListInherited(1)
    print(instance.__doc__)
```

In python console

```
>>> import test3
>>> help(test3)
```

Output:

```
Help on module test3:

NAME
    test3

FILE
    /home/mrdinkelman/PycharmProjects/testproject27/test3.py

DESCRIPTION
    Module documentation
    A small example of comments usage

CLASSES
    ListInherited

    class ListInherited
     |  Class ListInherited doc example
     |  This class use dir() function for list instance attributes
     |  
     |  Methods defined here:
     |  
     |  __init__(self, arg1)
     |      my constructor
     |      :param arg1: example value
     |      :return:
     |  
     |  __str__(self)
     |      to string conversion
     |      :return:
     |  
     |  attr_names(self)
     |      get attribute names
     |      :return: string
     |  
     |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |  Static methods defined here:
     |  
     |  my_static_method(count)
     |      static method comment example
     |      :param count:
     |      :return:

FUNCTIONS
    square(x)
        this function will return square(x) value
        :param x: any number
        :return: example doc for return

DATA
    spam = 40
```

Comment: Thanks. However, is the ":param" keyword recognized by help()? It seems that it print it as any other comment.